# Emit particles from plane with random velocity

Tags: particles

I have a plane. I want particles emitted in the normal direction, but have some randomness to both direction and speed.

I can't seem to find any options to randomize initial velocity.

Blender 2.8.2

Comment: This Q&A may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94859/how-do-i-evenly-emit-particles-from-a-surface/94860#94860

Comment: @MechtEngineer that question just says to add random velocity. It doesn't say how to do that.

Comment: In the bottom right hand corner of the image shown in the question, there is a "Velocity" panel, and in this panel there is a setting "Random". Therefore, I presume this controls the random velocity of the particles. There is further information here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Particle_Systems Please remember to post an answer if you find one!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Don't know how I didn't see that yesterday...